# Django recursive FK relationship modified after save()

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a recursive relationship: every node has one (possibly null) parent. Conversely, every parent has multiple children. I have a build_subtree method which takes information about a node and recursively builds and adds node to the reverse set of the parent FK relationship, children. This seems to work as expected until I save the root Node. Before the call to save(), root.children.count() > 0, after save root.children.count() == 0. (See code below) Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've seen several mentions of django-mptt and I may end up using it, but I really want to understand this first.

```
class Node(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children')
    nodeVal = models.TextField()
    nodeType = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    level = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def build_subtree(cls, nodeVal, nodeType, level, children):
        root = cls(nodeVal=nodeVal, nodeType=nodeType, level=level)
        for c in children:
            root.children.add(cls.build_subtree(c['nodeVal'], c['nodeType'], c['level'], c['children']))
        return root
```

Then inside the shell...

```
>>> child = {'nodeVal' : 'B', 'nodeType' : 'tag', 'level' : 1, 'children' : []}
>>> root = {'nodeVal' : 'A', 'nodeType' : 'tag', 'level' : 0, 'children' : [child]}
>>> n = Node.build_subtree(root['nodeVal'], root['nodeType'], root['level'], root['children'])
>>> n.children.count()
1
>>> n.save()
>>> n.children.count()
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your children don't receive reference to the parent:

```
>>> print n.children.all()[0].parent
None
```

In the `build_subtree` method, you're creating parent without saving it to the DB, but the `add()` method saves objects to the DB, and there is not FK to set, because parent does not exist yet!

You should probably replace class instantiation with a call to `cls.objects.create` or use a different creation order.